# In this Probability Density Function, am I doing it right?

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Consider a model consisting of random variables $X,Y$ and $Z: Y=Xw+Z$, where $Z∼U[−1,1]$.

Comment: The different solution is correct.  I am confused about your initial thoughts.

Comment: What part that you think is confusing? Can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: The solution is correct and I think the way you have written is also reasonably formal.

Comment: You dropped "initial thoughts" so I can't elaborate.

Comment: how can "$Z$ be independent to $X$ and $Y$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is right, other than talking about their independence ( which they are not  having the equality $Y=\omega X + Z$ means they cannot be ! ).

For writing it down you can do it this way (although your intuition is fine, it may not be for more complicated problems) :

Let $F_{Y|X=x}$ be the conditional CDF, and $f_{Y|X=x}$ the conditional PDF.

Recall $\frac{d}{da}F_{Y|X=x}(a)=f_{Y|X=x}(a)$ (fundamental theorem of calculus + definitions of CDF and PDF). Now calculate

For $a \in [\omega x-\frac{1}{2},\omega x+\frac{1}{2}]$

\begin{align}
F_{Y|X=x}(a) =& \mathbb{P}(Z \leq a-\omega x)
\\
=& a-\omega x - \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

hence $\frac{d}{da}F_{Y|X=x}(a)=1=f_{Y|X=x}(a)$ for $a \in [\omega x-\frac{1}{2},\omega x+\frac{1}{2}]$.